# Finding an object in db and attaching an extra param from another table in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables in my db: `accounts` and `transactions`. They look more or less like this, with relevant columns and example entries:

```
accounts

id |     uid     |
------------------
 1 |   "abcde"   |
 2 |   "qwert"   |
```

```
transactions

id | account_id | amount | balance | 
------------------------------------
 1 | 1          | 100    | 100     |
 2 | 1          | 200    | 300     |
 3 | 2          | 500    | 500     |
 4 | 2          | 300    | 800     |
```

So basically Account has many Transactions, and the transaction tells what the amount was + it shows the balance after adding that transaction to the previous balance. So last transaction tells us what the current balance on the account is.

Now I would like to fetch an account, having only its `uid`, but with a twist - I'd like to also fetch the balance, which would be the `balance` column of the last transaction (based on `id`) that belongs to that account. Ideally this will give me an object of the `Account` model, with the additional balance param accessible using `object[:balance]`.

I know that this would require a left outer join and a select that adds the balance param to the object, something like `select('accounts.*', 'transactions.balance as balance')` - plus picking up the last one, so ordering by id and limiting to 1 - but I have no idea how to construct this query (using activerecord methods or pure SQL), considering the fact that I only have access to the `uid` of the account, not its `id` which is referenced as the `account_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS tr
  FROM transactions AS t inner join accounts a on a.id = t.id
  where a.uid = 'qwert'
)
SELECT * FROM ranked WHERE tr = 1;
```